# RegEx (word : 123, 345, 567 -> word.123,word.345,word.567)

Tags: regex, concatenation, prefix

I regret I failed at resolving this regex problem and I dont expect light will come ever. Thus it's time to beg for help.
I have a long txt file, in which a repeated line is like that :

```
acteur: 634, 681, 731
```

I want to get it converted to :

```
Acteur.634,Acteur.681,Acteur.731
```

Of course, I dont want to alter any other lines. Only lines starting with word `acteur:` should be affected.

Here it is a snippet of my file (plain text) :

```
inbob: -1
mention: 
Il n'est pas distingué
acteur: 731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1934]
date2: 1934
(:remarque:Deuxième vérification faite : ok:)");

type: 
inbob: -1
mention: 
Comme un moineau
acteur: 634, 681, 731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1930]
date2: 1930
(:remarque::)");
```

Target is :

```
inbob: -1
mention: 
Il n'est pas distingué
Acteur.731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1934]
date2: 1934
(:remarque:Deuxième vérification faite : ok:)");

type: 
inbob: -1
mention: 
Comme un moineau
Acteur.634,Acteur.681,Acteur.731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1930]
date2: 1930
(:remarque::)");
```

Searching    `([0-9]+)`    and replacing with    `Acteur.$1`    gets the job done, yet altering all the file. I guess dont know how to limit the process to the lines starting with     `acteur:` and I know I'm missing the right way.

Thank you.

Comment: Which language or tool you're running?

Comment: I could provide you a solution only based on the language.

Comment: Hum, sorry if I forgot to mention language/tool is used ; naive answer is I'm playing with a text editor for Windows, like EditPad or SublimeText2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running PHP, the below regex would help you.

```
^(?!acteur:).*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:^acteur:\h+|\h+)
```

Use  the above regex in `preg_replace` and then replace the matched characters with `Acteur.`

`^(?!acteur:).*` Matches all the lines which starts with `acteur:` and the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the whole match to fail.

`^acteur:\h+` From the remaining string, this regex would match the part `acteur:` plus the following one or more space characters. `|` OR, `\h+` other remaining one or more space characters. Note that this won't match the spaces on the lines which doesn't starts with `acteur`  because we already skipped those lines.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eG6qA4/1)

```
$str = <<< EOT
inbob: -1
mention: 
Il n'est pas distingué
acteur: 731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1934]
date2: 1934
(:remarque:Deuxième vérification faite : ok:)");

type: 
inbob: -1
mention: 
Comme un moineau
acteur: 634, 681, 731
lieu: 
editeur: Les étoiles de la chanson
collection: 
numed: 
nbv: 
nbp: 
date: [1930]
date2: 1930
(:remarque::)");
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~^(?!acteur:).*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:^acteur:\h+|\h+)~um', 'Acteur.', $str);
```

Comment: Woooh. Clear and far more difficult I would expectit to be. Not easy to work with unless I find a capable software (Windows) -- looking for such a tool caused the delayed answer --. Thank you Avinash.